# firestore not creating document with setDoc

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When i add new user on my firebase database, it is created successfully on authentication and his profil picture is added successfully on the storage. The successuful toast is appearing. But the document with his informations is not created. i'm using the setDoc method to create de document.

It's a react app.

Help me please

firebase.config.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "AIzaSyCsnZPoO6LIhvXwxjKkJe60AvmkgNqYhqM",
   authDomain: "le-prof-e863b.firebaseapp.com",
   projectId: "le-prof-e863b",
   storageBucket: "le-prof-e863b.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "433335960615",
   appId: "1:433335960615:web:650aa77f403efff66f3a02",
   measurementId: "G-6N2HDEQVXV"
 };

 // Initialize Firebase
 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

 export const auth = getAuth(app)
 export const db = getFirestore(app)
 export const storage = getStorage(app)

 export default app
```

Signup.jsx

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { setDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore';

import { auth } from '../../firebase.config'
import { storage } from '../../firebase.config';
import { db } from '../../firebase.config';

const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)

  const user = userCredential.user

  const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${username}`)
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file)

  uploadTask.on((error)=>{
    toast.error(error.message)
  },()=>{
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async(downloadURL)=>{
      
      // update user profile
      await updateProfile(user, {
        displayName: username,
        photoURL: downloadURL
      })

      // store user data in firestore database
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), {
        uid: user.uid,
        displayName: username,
        phone,
        email,
        sex: userSex,
        photoURL: downloadURL
      })
    })
  })
  
  toast.success('Account created')
  setLoading(false)

} catch (error) {
  setLoading(false)
  toast.error('Something went wrong')
}
}
```

Comment: That `toast.success('Account created')` and `setLoading(false)` must be right after `setDoc()` statement within the `then()` block, can you check if the toast still shows up and if there are any errors in the browser console?

Comment: The toast isn't showing up and it is still on loading but any error is displayed in the console.

Comment: Seems like, promise is not resolved try `await setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), { ... }).then(() => { ... })` and move the `toast.success` message inside the `then` block.